# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\} $ is connected for $n > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

> Prove that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\} $ is connected for $n > 1$.

I don't understand where to start proving this since

$$\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} = (-\infty,0)^n \cup (0, \infty)^n $$

Which is the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets, so it can't be connected. Obviously I won't be told to prove something is true that isn't so I know I'm missing something.

We have proven that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected using this theorem:

Let S be a topological space, and let $T_0$ and $\{T_w\}_{w\in W} $ be connected subsets of S. Assume that $T_0 \cap T_w \neq \emptyset $ for each w. Then $T_0 \cup \left( \cup_{w \in W} T_w \right)$ is connected.

Using the first connected set {0} and the indexed ones as lines that go through the point {0} indexed by the unit sphere.

I was hoping to do something similar with this problem, but I can't see a way to do that. Help would be appreciated. And apologies for any Latex mistakes. I'll try to fix them but I'm on vacation and only have my phone currently.

Comment: $-\{0\}$ in this case means without the origin only.  Look at the case of $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, it is the entire plane without the central dot.  You say it is equal somehow to $(-\infty,0)^n\cup (0,\infty)^n$, but in the case of $n=2$ that seems like you are talking about the lower left-hand quadrant and the upper right-hand quadrant.  What happened to the point $(-1,1)$ or any other point in the upper-left quadrant?

Comment: Oh duh, I was looking at it like it was still just R. That clears that up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:  It's usually way easier to show path connected than connected.  Path connected implies connected, it's stronger.  So take two arbitrary points and show you can connect them with a path.   There are two cases:  The points are not on the same line as the origin on opposite sides (The easy case), and they are:  (The almost as easy case)

Can you manage?

Comment: That sounds manageable, but I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean by the points are not on the same line as the origin on opposite sides. And they are. Can you please elaborate on this? Sorry if it's something obvious I'm missing

Comment: @BenRay take the case of $\Bbb R^2$ for example.  Suppose we want to show that there exists a path between $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$.  We can take a straightline path $f(t)=(-1+2t,1)$ for $t\in [0,1]$.  This satisfies $f(0)=(-1,1)$ and $f(1)=(1,1)$ and is continuous, all points of which are in the set $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$.  Now... what if the points we want to check are $(-1,-1),(1,1)$.  We cannot simply use a *line* between them as that would pass through $(0,0)$, but perhaps we can use a suitable curve, for example traveling along the outside of the sphere. Formalize this for arbitrary points and $n$

Comment: @Jmoravitz ah okay I see how I should do this. This makes the distinction Alan was making clearer. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 10):

Your "formula" for $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$ is wrong. Draw $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you will understand why.

If you want to avoid usage of path-connectedness, do the following. For $n>1$, take $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$ given by $A:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n > 0\}$ and $B:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n<0\}$. $A$ and $B$ are clearly connected (both in fact homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$). Since the closure of connected sets is connected, $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are connected. But $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ have points in common. Therefore, their union is connected. But their union is the entire $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$ .

Fun exercise: Where does this fail for $\mathbb{R}$?

> "But $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ have points in common" - They don't, for $n=1$.

Comment: I like this proof and it is probably what the book I'm reading was going for since it hasn't introduced path-connectedness yet. Thank you. However I'm now interested in the proof of path-connectedness that Alan is hinting toward.

Comment: @BenRay This answer was intended exactly for diversity, not for substitution.  : )

Comment: doesn't $0$ is comment point of $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ for $n=1$?

Comment: @Alex No, since we are looking at $A,B$ as subspaces of $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: ahhh! right, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Alozio Macedo Hello, could you explain why A and B are connected? Obviously they are, but how would one procceed to proof this assumption? (without resulting to the path definition)

Answer (score 1):

$n$-dimensional polar coordinates give rise to a continuous surjection from the cartesian product of connected intervals to $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a path from any point to the unit disc,
$r(t)= ((1-t)+{t \over \|x\|}) x$

Now all that remains is to show that the unit disk is connected. Pick $u_1,u_2$ on the unit disk. Let $v_1=u_1$ and
$v_2$ on the unit disc in the span of $u_1,u_2$ such that $v_1 \bot v_2$.

Now consider the path $\rho(\theta) = (\cos \theta) v_1 + (\sin \theta) v_2$,
and show that $\rho(\theta)$ is on the unit disk for all $\theta$ and that there is some $\theta'$ such that $\rho(\theta') = u_2$.

Here is an explicit construction: Let
$v_2 = { u_2 -\langle u_1, u_2 \rangle u_1 \over \| u_2 -\langle u_1, u_2 \rangle u_1  \| }$. Note that $v_2$ is on the unit disk and we have
$u_2 = \| u_2 -\langle u_1, u_2 \rangle u_1  \| v_2 + \langle u_1, u_2 \rangle u_1$. Now check that $\| u_2 -\langle u_1, u_2 \rangle u_1  \|^2 + (\langle u_1, u_2 \rangle u_1)^2 = 1$, hence there is some $\theta'$ such that
$\sin \theta' = \langle u_1, u_2 \rangle u_1$ and
$\cos \theta' = \| u_2 -\langle u_1, u_2 \rangle u_1  \|$, from which we have
$\rho(\theta') = u_2$. Hence the map $\rho:[0,\theta'] \to S^{n-1}$ is a path connecting $u_1,u_2$ in $S^{n-1}$.