# why $\overline {A} \cup \overline{B}=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}?$

Tags: general-topology

My main  motivation came from my previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961385/prove-that-mathbbr2-setminus-0-is-connected)

After that i read this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1871279/557708)
After reading i have some confusion in my mind given below

> Here is an outline of the [Aloizio Macedo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59234/aloizio-macedo) solution

> If you want to avoid usage of path-connectedness, do the following. For $n>1$, take $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$ given by $A:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n > 0\}$ and $B:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n<0\}$. $A$ and $B$ are clearly connected (both in fact homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$). Since the closure of connected sets is connected, $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are connected. But $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ have points in common. Therefore, their union is connected. But their union is the entire $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$ .

> Fun exercise: Where does this fail for $\mathbb{R}$?

> "But $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ have points in common" - They don't, for $n=1$.

**My thinking** : If $A:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n > 0\}$ the  $\overline{A}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n \ge 0\}$ simliarly  if $B:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n<0\}$ then $\overline B:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n\le0\}$

Now $\overline {A} \cap \overline{B}= \{0\}\neq \emptyset$

$\overline A \cup \overline{ B}= \mathbb{R}^n$

for $n=1$ we have $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^1 \mid x_1 > 0\} $and $B:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^1 \mid x_1<0\}$

$\overline{A}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^1 \mid x_1 \ge 0\} $and $\overline{B}:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^1 \mid x_1\le 0\}$  then it give $\overline {A}\cap \overline {B} =\{0\} \neq \emptyset$

Here I have two confusion given below

$1.$ why $\overline {A} \cup \overline{B}=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}?$

$2.$ why it fail in $\mathbb{R} ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. He meant the closure in $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ (with its relative topology).
2. In $\Bbb R$ we would have $A=(0,\infty), B=(-\infty,0)$, and taking closures in $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ we would get $\overline A=A$ and $\overline B=B$, since we are in the relative topology of $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. This sets don't have common points, so the argument doesn't work.

Comment: thanks u @Darsen  but i have some confusion in $1.$ that If $A=\overline{A}:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n > 0\}$, $B=\overline{B}:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n<0\}$ .Then what will be their intersection i mean $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}=??$

Comment: No, no. $\overline A=A$ and $\overline B=B$ happens in the case $n=1$. In general you have $\overline A=\{x\in\Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}:x_n\ge0\}$ and $\overline B=\{x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}:x_n\le0\}$. For $n>1$ you can take points like $(1,0,\ldots,0)$ which is both in $\overline A$ and $\overline B$. For $n=1$ you can't, since we're working in $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: oks one more confusion why $(1,0,0,...)$ which both in $\bar{A}$ and $\bar {B}? $ since $\overline{B}$ is the set which contain only negative number i mean $(1,0,0.....) \notin \overline{B}$ but $(-1,0,0.....) \in \overline{B}$

Comment: Note that when defining $A$ and $B$ we put the condition $x_n>0$ and $x_n<0$ respectively. $x_n$ is the last component of a point $x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$, so when taking the closures, and thus allowing $x_n=0$ in both $\overline A$ and $\overline B$, we have that $(1,0,\ldots,0)\in\overline A\cap\overline B$. This is why the argument doesn't work for $n=1$, since $x_n$ and $x$ are the same thing (there's only one component in $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$).

Comment: oks one last more doubts  ...u mean $x=(x_1,x_2,......x_n) ?$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: thanks u got it ..now completely understands @Darsen